# Find and Replace with parameter in Linux

Tags: linux, file, variables, replace

I have many files that contain line like this one:

```
_str = floatNumber_ (including spaces)
```

And I would like multiply that float by a constant and have the result there like:

```
_str = 4xfloatNumber_
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="="};{print $1 "= " 4*$2}' < src_file > dest_file
```

Details:

- `BEGIN{FS="="}`: define `=` as field separator,
- `{print $1 "= " 4*$2}` make the operation you want,
- `< src_file`: read data from `src_file`,
- `> dest_file`: write data to `dest_file`.

And if you have several files to process:

```
# where *.* are the files you want to process
for i in *.* 
do
    awk 'BEGIN{FS="="};{print $1 "= " 4*$2}' < $i > $i.out
done
```

Comment: There are a few problems with that solution - one is every _= something_  goes into _= num*4_ (including strings), also I don't want to change every value, but only those in specific lines. Last problem is that it makes _= 0_ at the beginning of some lines.